# Woocommerce: Changing "Review Configuration" text?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce store with a couple of multiple-step Composite Products.

The last step in ordering one of these products is labeled "Review Configuration", and I'm trying to find a way to be able to edit that text so it reads "Review Design."

Here's the page in question. Or one of them, anyway:

http://204.197.244.57/~silverpennies/product/custom-necklace/

I tried going into /plugins/woocommerce-composite-products/includes/class-wc-cp-display.php and on line 107, there's this:

```
'i18n_final_step'                       => __( 'Review Configuration', 'woocommerce-composite-products' ),
```

I changed that, but it didn't seem to make a difference on the site. Does anyone know how I could change that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I wanted the text 'Review Configuration' to read 'Confirm Design'.

I managed to change it by editing the following:

Change the text on line 57 of:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-composite-products/templates/single-product/composite-summary.php

So from this:

```
$title      = __( 'Review Configuration', 'woocommerce-composite-products' );
```

to this in my case:

```
$title      = __( 'Confirm Design', 'woocommerce-composite-products' );
```

Hope that helps :)

Also, at the bottom of the page, depending on how you have your composite products displayed, you may also need to change the text 'Review Configuration' in the following file as well on line 20:

wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-composite-products/templates/single-product/composite-add-to-cart.php

```
?><div id="composite_data_<?php echo $product_id; ?>" class="cart composite_data <?php echo isset( $_REQUEST[ 'add-to-cart' ] ) ? 'composite_added_to_cart' : ''; ?>" data-item_id="review" data-composite_settings="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $product->add_to_cart_form_settings() ) ); ?>" data-nav_title="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Review Configuration', 'woocommerce-composite-products' ) ); ?>" data-scenario_data="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $product->get_current_scenario_data() ) ); ?>" data-price_data="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $product->get_composite_price_data() ) ); ?>" data-container_id="<?php echo $product_id; ?>" style="display:none;"><?php
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could attach the code on that line that you changed/needed to be changed for context.

Comment: Yes Bob, you're right I should have added that, I've edited my original answer and added the line of code that needs changing.

Answer (score 1):

I edited both of those lines in those files and it didn't change the "Review Configuration" text for me. I even tried using the Quick Localization plugin with the text domain and still didn't work.

I found that I needed to edit the file here: /woocommerce-composite-products/includes/class-wc-cp-display.php on line 199.

`'i18n_final_step' => _x( 'Review Configuration', 'final step navigation button text', 'woocommerce-composite-products' ),`

Hope this can help someone else looking for help with this.

Answer (score 0):

A more non destructive way is to use a language file and replace the configuration string with your own custom string.

I have done this before by uploading a custom language file `woocommerce-composite-products-en_US.mo` and `woocommerce-composite-products-en_US.po` to the folder:

`wp-content > languages > plugins`

I downloaded the plugin's original language file and edited it with [Poedit](https://poedit.net/download).